# Host options for an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, cordova, app-store, host

I'm developing an iPhone/android app and, in the case of iphone one, I need to host it asap. I am about to finish it but the average time to be published in the AppStore is about 7 days once been aproved. I was looking for any othe host but I'm not sure if they would be work as AppStore, I mean: downloading by everycustoner without doing throught Cydia or things like that.

Any suggestion or experiences?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have an enterprise account, you can use [Enterprise Distribution for in-house apps](https://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/?lang=en-us#app43ad6a6a). But you probably don't, or you wouldn't be asking this question.

If it's a very limited number of devices and you have personal contact with all potential users:

- You could deploy it on devices yourself.
- You could use ad-hoc beta distribution (made easy with [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com), for instance).

Other than that - there are no other legitimate options.

If you want widespread, "ordinary" distribution of a native app on iOS, you'll have to go through the app store, period.

Answer (score 0):

Other than for time-limited plus number-of-devices-limited beta test distribution (Ad Hoc and/or testflight), the only host option for unlimited distribution of an iOS app to ordinary customers with stock devices is waiting for an app to be approved and hosted on Apple's iTunes App store.